# What are networking technologies to distribute the file faster with storing on more replicas?

Tags: distributed-systems, computer-networks

Question: Suppose you launch a job on 10,000 machines in your own data centre. The job is slow to start because all the machines are trying to load the same large executable ﬁle. Name two networking technologies you could use to distribute the ﬁle faster, in addition to storing it on more replicas. Explain why each is appropriate.

I think one option would be peer-to-peer technology (bitTorrent). Second option can be IP Multitasking, but it does not replicas files and store in other nodes. What could be other option for this question?

Comment: Mirroring is another option.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this question is on-topic here - perhaps it's better on serverfault.

Comment: IP multitasking?  What's that?  Are you sure you're not thinking of something else?